# How can I start firefox from a batch file in win7?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

This command works fine from the Win 7 command line:

\progra~2\mozill~1\firefox.exe https://client.schwab.com

But it doesn't work from a batch file.

I tried preceding it with 'start' but that doesn't run either.

Comment: I switched the script to perl, and gave it: $ret=`start C:/progra~2/mozill~1/firefox.exe https://client.schwab.com', and that worked fine. So, what's the matter with my batch file processor?

Comment: Your command with the short filename and with the quoted-longfilename worked fine for me in Win7.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't try `start "" "C:\users\YourUserName\Desktop\firefox.exe"`

Or `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rest_of_the_path"`

Comment: Yes, I did. I got the error message "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'. That's why I switched to the Dos short names.

Comment: @user1067305 - quotes are needed for paths with spaces. You definitely need to use start. The edited code above will open the website using Firefox.